# How to allow a user totally control local web server?

Tags: webserver

I installed a local web-server (apache2, php5, mysql).
All the time I want to edit some permissions or to create a folder or to add some lines to hosts I need to login as a root.

Do I need to grant privileges by the root all the time for this folders and files or is there a way to make it at once? Maybe i should reinstall webserver by the user i want to use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by giving the file ownership to the user. Use chown command to do that.

ex: `chown -R user website_folder`

[-R is for recursively change file ownership; change user and the folder accordingly].

And make sure you have write permission too. You can set write permission with chmod.

ex: `chmod +x webpage.html`

[The above command will give the write permission to the current user]

Comment: This means i have to do it every time i want to create a project.. Or if i change user to basic webserver folders i would not have to change it after?

Comment: No, you can do chown -R user /var/www. it will change all permission. But don't change permissions of /etc/php5 (or any file in /etc/ ;). It is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is add the `user` to the group used by the web server (and the group of the web files)

```
usermod -aG www-apache $USER
```

normally, the apache config files are write privileges to `www-apache` group (and the dir in `/var/www`)